# Angular: Using ng-disabled if forms in partials in child controllers have ng-invalid attribute

Tags: angularjs

I've been struggling with this for a few hours, and I'm coming up blank. I wouldn't build this this way, but this is someone else's code and refactoring it all is way beyond the scope of my part of the project. I need something that works within the way it's currently built. Here is a rough approximation of what the html looks like:

```
<div ng-controller=OuterController as outerController>
    <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="?????">Save</button>
    <div ng-controller="PartialController as partialController>
        <div partial which can be replicated a bunch of times and called recursively>
            <form name="partialForm></form
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, there can be a ton of instances of partialForm within the dom, which may be different degrees of childhood from the OuterController, and I want to be able to check if any of them have ng-invalid for the ng-disabled on the save button.

Any thoughts? :)

Comment: You would probably need a variable in the OuterController controller code, such as a boolean IsSaveEnabled. Then in the view ng-disabled=!IsSaveEnabled. Now in each partial controller, there would be a callback to the parent outer controller, which would set the IsSaveEnabled variable to false if there are any invalid children.

Comment: Any idea how to structure that callback?